# Add a value inside an object applying conditional logic

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects. I pulled from the array the keys to create another array.

```js
const data = [
    {
      key: '1',
      name: 'John Brown',
      age: 32,
      address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
    },
    {
      key: '2',
      name: 'Joe Black',
      age: 42,
      address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
    },
    {
      key: '3',
      name: 'Jim Green',
      age: 32,
      address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
    },
    {
      key: '4',
      name: 'Jim Red',
      age: 32,
      address: 'London No. 2 Lake Park',
    },
  ];

const el = {num: 22}


const res  =Object.keys(data[0]).map(i => {
    return {
        title: i,
        dataIndex: i,
        key: i,
        width: '30%',
        ...el
    }
})



console.log(res)
```

How to apply in the code bellow the next logic : to change `...el` to: `i !== 'age' ? ...el : " "`, meaning to apply `...el` taking into acount if `i !== 'age'` ?

```js
return {
        title: i,
        dataIndex: i,
        key: i,
        width: '30%',
        // i want to change: ...el to: i !== 'age' ? ...el : " "

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const el = {
  num: 22
};

const i = 'age';

const firstObject = {
  title: i,
  dataIndex: i,
  key: i,
  width: '30%',
  ...(i !== 'age' && el)
};

const j = 'foo';

const secondObject = {
  title: j,
  dataIndex: j,
  key: j,
  width: '30%',
  ...(j !== 'age' && el)
}

console.log(firstObject);
console.log(secondObject);
```